# RegEx expression to keep first appearance of word grouping

Tags: regex

I have the following RegEx `(\[[^]]+])(?=.*\1)`

which identifies the **first** set of appearances of a duplicate word group inside a string (*each word group is enclosed between [ ] brackets*). However, I am trying to come up with a RegEx that identifies the **last** set of appearances of a duplicate word group. Reason being, I need to remove duplicate word groups while retaining the order in which each group appears in the overall string.

Using the following string as an example whereby only *[John Smith]* and *[Jane Doe]* are duplicate word groups:

> [John Smith][John Smith][Mr. Smith][Jane Doe][Mrs. Doe][John Smith][Jane Doe][Doe][John][Smith John][John Smith Sr]

After using my RegEx in a RegEx Replace formula, I get the below:

> [Mr. Smith][Mrs. Doe][John Smith][Jane Doe][Doe][John][Smith John][John Smith Sr]"

However, I need my RegEx Replace formula to give me:

> [John Smith][Mr. Smith][Jane Doe][Mrs. Doe][Doe][John][Smith John][John Smith Sr]

I have tried many ways to achieve the latter with no luck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: apologies, I am using low-code software (Alteryx), which I believe uses C programming language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering infinite-width lookbehinds:

```js
(\[[^\][]+])(?<=\1.*\1)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/eitZ58/2/).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\][]+                  any character except: '\]', '[' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]                        ']'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
```

Answer (score 0):

Many regex engines do not support variable-length lookbehinds, but most support variable-length lookaheads. When working with an engine that supports variable-length lookaheads, but not variable-length lookbehinds, one approach that often works is to reverse the string, modify the (reversed) string with a regex and then reverse the resulting string. That approach could be used here.

Suppose, for example, the string were

```
"[John Smith][John Smith][Mr. Smith][Jane Doe][John Smith][Jane Doe][Doe]"
```

Reversing the string produces

```
"]eoD[]eoD enaJ[]htimS nhoJ[]eoD enaJ[]htimS .rM[]htimS nhoJ[]htimS nhoJ["
```

We now convert matches of the following expression to empty strings:

```
(\][^[]*\[)(?=.*\1)
```

which produces

```
"]eoD[]eoD enaJ[]htimS .rM[]htimS nhoJ["
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8mAwNU/1)

Lastly, we reverse that string to obtain

```
"[John Smith][Mr. Smith][Jane Doe][Doe]"
```

The regular expression can be written in *free-spacing* mode to make it self-documenting:

```
(        # begin capture group 1
  \]     # match ']' 
  [^[]*  # match one or more (as many as possible) chars other than '['
  \[     # match '['
)        # end capture group 1
(?=      # begin a positive lookahead
  .*     # match one or more (as many as possible) chars
  \1     # match the content of capture group 1
)        # end the positive lookahead
```

At first glance this may seem a kludge, but since reversing a string is so easy in any language it does provide a useful work-around in some cases. Mind you, doing what you want to do here in code is pretty easy in most languages. In Ruby, for example, you could write (`str` being a variable holding the string)

```
str.scan(/\[[^\]]*\]/).uniq.join
```